How can I find the page number where the ActiveCell is, of a Multi PrintArea on an excel sheet?
I'm trying to find the page number where the activated cell is located, but it doesn't work.

I'm asking for help.
As shown in the attached picture, I would like to know the number of the page where the activated cell is located.
The code used is :
Function FindPage(r As Range) As Integer
'Function written by Luke M
'Input a single Range, outputs page that range is in
'Output is 0 if not in print range
Dim VCount As Long
Dim HCount As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim V()
Dim H()
Dim i, X, Y
With r.Worksheet
    'setup our boundary conditions
    VCount = .VPageBreaks.Count + 1
    HCount = .HPageBreaks.Count + 1
    
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row
    LastCol = .UsedRange.Columns.Count + .UsedRange.Column
    
    If r.Row > LastRow Or r.Column > LastCol Then
        FindPage = 0
        Exit Function
    End If
   
    ReDim V(1 To VCount)
    ReDim H(1 To HCount)
   
    'Populate our arrays
    For i = 1 To VCount - 1
        V(i) = .VPageBreaks(i).Location.Column
    Next i
    For i = 1 To HCount - 1
        H(i) = .HPageBreaks(i).Location.Row
    Next i
   
    V(VCount) = LastCol
    H(HCount) = LastRow
   
    'Where does our cell fall?
    For X = 1 To VCount
        If r.Column < V(X) Then Exit For
    Next X
    For Y = 1 To HCount
        If r.Row < H(Y) Then Exit For
    Next Y
    
    FindPage = Y + (X - 1) * HCount

End With

End Function


"doesn't work" what exactly does it do instead of work?  Seems to work fine for me.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

This would be a bit of work - you'd need to check each Area in ws.Range(ws.PageSetup.PrintArea).Areas (where ws is r.Worksheet) and within each Area check the HPageBreaks and VPageBreaks to see which if any fall within the area, then figure out if printing is "down then over" or "over then down" to determine the order of pages within each area.

Select a cell on page 2 and run it. It says page 3.

Please reply. It would be even better if there was source code.

Updated my answer with a more-dynamic approach....

If this is a fixed print area and you don't need the code to be dynamic and account for many different print layouts then you can do something simple like this:
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print WhichPage(Selection)
End Sub

'Check which page contains the range `c`
'  Returns zero if no page contains the range
Function WhichPage(c As Range) As Long
    Dim arrPages, i As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    'page areas on your sheet
    arrPages = Array("B2:G20", "H2:K20", "M3:R12", "M13:R22")
    
    Set ws = c.Worksheet
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrPages)
        If Not Application.Intersect(c.Cells(1), ws.Range(arrPages(i))) Is Nothing Then
            WhichPage = i + 1 'arrPages is zero-based
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function

If you need something more complex/dynamic then this code works to enumerate all pages on a sheet where there's an assigned PrintArea:
Sub CheckCustomPrintAreas()
    
    Dim downThenOver As Boolean
    Dim pa As Range, a As Range, ws As Worksheet, pb As Object
    Dim pageRows As Collection, pageCols As Collection, numAreaPages As Long
    Dim col As Long, rw As Long, pageCount As Long, sel As Range
    Dim outerRng As Range, innerRng As Range, pageRange As Range
    Dim outer As Collection, inner As Collection
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    If Len(ws.PageSetup.PrintArea) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'no specific print area
    
    Set pa = ws.Range(ws.PageSetup.PrintArea) 'get the print range
    downThenOver = ws.PageSetup.Order = xlDownThenOver 'check print order
    Debug.Print "Print order:", _
          IIf(downThenOver, "Down then over", "Over then down")
    
    Set sel = Selection.Cells(1)
    Debug.Print "Selection:", sel.Address
    
    pageCount = 0
    For Each a In pa.Areas 'check each distinct area in the defined PrintArea
        
        Set pageRows = New Collection
        Set pageCols = New Collection
        
        'rows of pages...
        rw = a.Row 'first row of area
        For Each pb In ws.HPageBreaks
            If Not Intersect(pb.Location, a) Is Nothing Then
                pageRows.Add ws.Range(ws.Cells(rw, 1), _
                                      ws.Cells(pb.Location.Row - 1, 1)).EntireRow
                rw = pb.Location.Row
            End If
        Next pb
        pageRows.Add ws.Range(ws.Cells(rw, 1), _
                              ws.Cells(a.Rows(a.Rows.Count).Row, 1)).EntireRow
        
        'columns of pages...
        col = a.Column
        For Each pb In ws.VPageBreaks
            If Not Intersect(pb.Location, a) Is Nothing Then
                pageCols.Add ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, col), _
                                      ws.Cells(1, pb.Location.Column - 1)).EntireColumn
                col = pb.Location.Column
            End If
        Next pb
        pageCols.Add ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, col), _
                              ws.Cells(1, a.Columns(a.Columns.Count).Column)).EntireColumn
        
        numAreaPages = pageRows.Count * pageCols.Count 'how many pages in this area?
        
        Debug.Print vbLf & "----Checking Area: " & a.Address & " " & numAreaPages & " pages -----"
        Debug.Print "Area rows: " & ListRanges(pageRows)
        Debug.Print "Area columns: " & ListRanges(pageCols)
        Debug.Print "Pages:"
        
        'are we counting pages across and down, or down and across?
        Set outer = IIf(downThenOver, pageCols, pageRows)
        Set inner = IIf(downThenOver, pageRows, pageCols)
        
        'enumerage page ranges
        For Each outerRng In outer
            For Each innerRng In inner
                pageCount = pageCount + 1
                Set pageRange = Application.Intersect(outerRng, innerRng)
                Debug.Print pageCount, pageRange.Address(False, False)
                If Not Application.Intersect(pageRange, sel) Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print , "^^^ Selection is here!"
                End If
            Next innerRng
        Next outerRng
       
    Next a
End Sub

'for debug outputs....
Function ListRanges(col As Collection) As String
    Dim rng As Range, s As String
    For Each rng In col
        s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, ", ", "") & rng.Address(False, False)
    Next rng
    ListRanges = s
End Function

Test print area:

Debug output:
Print order:  Over then down
Selection:    $M$30

----Checking Area: $B$3:$K$20 2 pages -----
Area rows: 3:20
Area columns: B:G, H:K
Pages:
 1            B3:G20
 2            H3:K20

----Checking Area: $M$4:$R$22 4 pages -----
Area rows: 4:11, 12:22
Area columns: M:O, P:R
Pages:
 3            M4:O11
 4            P4:R11
 5            M12:O22
 6            P12:R22

----Checking Area: $G$26:$P$40 6 pages -----
Area rows: 26:32, 33:40
Area columns: G:K, L:M, N:P
Pages:
 7            G26:K32
 8            L26:M32
              ^^^ Selection is here!
 9            N26:P32
 10           G33:K40
 11           L33:M40
 12           N33:P40


My main goal is to know the cell address of the page. If you think you know the address in advance, you won't ask questions, right?
Anyway, thank you.

The core of the problem is that if there are multiple print settings areas, the page cannot be properly identified.

I thought it would never work, but you solved it. You are the best.
Thank you very very much. If I'm next to you, I want to buy you something delicious^^

It did take me a while but it was an interesting challenge, so thanks for posting your question!

I always worry a lot about various questions. We will consider the number of cases from various angles and try to solve them. I am grateful that my question was registered as the main question, and I am very grateful for your answer.

I have checked your code from various angles and it works flawlessly. It is very good.
One more question is whether I can find the area without going through the routine.

"whether I can find the area without going through the routine" I'm not sure what you mean by that?

You have to run the routine from page 1 to the last to know the page number where the active cell is located. If you can check it right away without running the routine, I expect that the work speed will greatly improve. If the number of pages is very large, it may take a long time to find the page.

You are the best for solving it.
I'm interpreting your code now and I'm almost done, but the more I learn, the more I admire your ideas.

I am Korean and just an ordinary person, but if you ever want to visit Korea, please contact me. If I have time, I will run until my feet sweat.

I am an ordinary person too!  You can exit out of the loop once you find the page with the selection: no need to continue at that point.  I will find some time to refactor a bit to make a function which will return as soon as it finds the page.

I know that too. What I mean is, you have to have a routine until you find it. Anyway, thank you.

Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.
